# Copy table details to same table with updated values - MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my table details.

```
Id(A.inc)| Title   | StartDate
1        | Program | 2016-11-11T22:05:00 
2        | Songs   | 2016-11-11T22:10:00 
3        | Speech  | 2016-11-11T22:15:00 
4        | News    | 2016-11-11T22:20:00 
5        | Debate  | 2016-11-11T22:25:00
```

I need to copy all the above details into the same table with updated values of next day in `StartDate` column and `ID` should be unique auto incremented value.

Here is the details what am expecting is,

```
Id(A.inc)| Title   | StartDate
6        | Program | 2016-11-12T22:05:00 
7        | Songs   | 2016-11-12T22:10:00 
8        | Speech  | 2016-11-12T22:15:00 
9        | News    | 2016-11-12T22:20:00 
10       | Debate  | 2016-11-12T22:25:00
```

Is it possible with mysql? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your `Id` column is AUTO_INCREMENT-ed and you just want to copy data, not replace. For that, you can try this:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (Id, Title, StartDate)
SELECT Id, Title, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(StartDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%dT%k:%i:%s')
FROM your_table
WHERE Id BETWEEN 1 and 5;
```

Or simply omit the `Id` column, because AUTO_INCREMENT-ed column will automatically increment its value.

```
INSERT INTO your_table (Title, StartDate)
SELECT Title, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(StartDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%dT%k:%i:%s')
FROM your_table
WHERE Id BETWEEN 1 and 5;
```

More about date and time formatting: [MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Its great, but i need to keep "T" as separator between date and time :(